# date comparison only compares years

Tags: javascript, html, date

Consider this code:

```
var from = new Date(document.getElementById("from").value);
var to = new Date(document.getElementById("to").value);
var yeardate = new Date(from.setMonth(from.getMonth()+12));

if (from.getTime() > to.getTime()) {
    alert(from.getTime() > to.getTime());
}
```

The fields are html5 date fields.

For example I use this:

```
from: 2015-06-30

to: 2018-07-31
```

it outputs false, but when I do this:

```
from: 2015-06-30

to: 2015-07-31
```

It outputs true while it should still be false because 06-30 is not greater than 07-31.

It looks like it only checks the year, how should I fix this?

Edit:

As suggested by @Laxmikant Dange, I tried the following.

```
alert((new Date('2015-06-30').getTime() > new Date('2015-07-31').getTime()));
```

it now returns false, but when I store the object to a variable, like this:

```
var from = new Date('2015-06-30');
var to = new Date('2015-07-31');
alert(from.getTime() > to.getTime());
```

It returns `true` again.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: The last one returns false for me. http://jsfiddle.net/ayg6bm4u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what is the value of date elements, There might be problem. here is your values and it returning false for both cases.

The value returned by the getTime() method is the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) is reference.

so it is not comparing only years.

```js
console.log("case 1",new Date('2015-06-30').getTime() > new Date('2018-07-31').getTime());
console.log("case 2",new Date('2015-06-30').getTime() > new Date('2015-07-31').getTime());
```

The problem in your code is with this line.

```
var yeardate = new Date(from.setMonth(from.getMonth()+12));
```

you are adding 12 months in from.
Comment this line, you will get expected result.

Comment: this is really wierd, I tested your code, it returned false on both cases when I did what you did. But when I put them into a variable it becomes true again.

Comment: @morbidCode, try to console values of date fields, check what is returns,

Comment: The date object containing the "from" field returned 1467244800000, and th date object containing the "to" field returned 1438300800000

Comment: @morbidCode, its because you are adding 12 months in from date. check 3rd line in your code.

Comment: yes, I understand now, thanks. But when I return the date, is it really one day off? Like in our example new Date('2015-06-30') return jun 29?